# XAMPP Wordpress install - WP-Admin formatting unusable

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, wp-admin

Putting our company website on localhost for testing, etc. All working OK, apart from WP-Admin: lets me login OK, but the format of the site is unusable - image attached.

Have checked permalinks, etc. which are working OK for rest of website. It is just WP-Admin that I'm having trouble with.

Anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance.

Darren.

[WP-Admin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55j4R.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/) steps

You have a problem in CSS style link, it may cause on your database or maybe on one file which has been hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The link confirms the manual steps I took, so that's all OK. Not sure how to find the code that could be doing this, but will have a look.

Comment: open your console panel in the Google chrome or Firefox and you will see what is the broken link

Answer (score 0):

Copied over WP-Admin files from a fresh install and now works.

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, Babak.